# ImageView inside StackView moved to the edge of the screen on iOS 11

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios10, ios11, uistackview

I've got a view that contains vertical `StackView`:

1. Alignment - Fill
2. Distribution - Fill Proportionally
3. Spacing - 15

that contains several horizontal `StackViews`:

1. Alignment - Fill
2. Distribution - Fill Proportionally
3. Spacing - 10

in which there is an `ImageView` and `Label` which can have text in 2 lines.

This is how this particular row looks like on iOS 10:
[image]

And this is how this view looks like on iOS 11:
[image]

The `ImageView` is moved to the edge of the device screen and text is starting from the position where image should be. Important information about this bug is that this behaviour is only when this is possible to fit the text as if there was no image. If the text is only a bit longer, then this view looks like this on both iOS version:
[image]

It looks like the `ImageView` is ignored and system is trying to fit text first if it can then image is moved away.

I tested this on 6 devices: 3 with iOS 11 and 3 with iOS 10 and it seems like this problem is related to the system version.

What are possible solutions or workarounds for this problem?